# Number Format Exception for Large value

Tags: java, numberformatexception

This block of code gives Number Format Exception on input 600000 in `n`

```
import java.util.*;
class SpoTwo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int testcase,n,answer;
    long bin;
    String s;
    testcase=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<testcase;i++){
        n=sc.nextInt();
        s=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        bin=Integer.parseInt(s);
        answer=(int)Math.pow(2,bin*2);
        System.out.println(answer%1000000007);
    }
    }
```

}
Exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10010010011111000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at SpoTwo.main(SpoTwo.java:12)`

Comment: Why do you think it does? What's the represenation of 600000 in binary? And what happens when you use `parseInt` on it?

Comment: I have added Exception

Answer (score 3):

The binary representation of `600000` is `10010010011111000000`. This is not a valid base 10 integer. It is a valid base 2 integer. Use

```
bin = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
```

[Here's the method's javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

The overloaded `parseInt` method you were using

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if
>   the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the
>   `parseInt(java.lang.String, int)` method.

Comment: Thanks i forgot this.

Comment: I want to retain the binary value and want to store in variable

Comment: @Johnsmith You are already doing that with your `n`, `s`, and `bin` variables.

Comment: In which data type can i hold this binary value

Comment: @Johnsmith Do you want to store it as a `String` or as an `int`/`Integer`? It depends what you want to do with it.

Comment: @John Use `Long.parseLong` instead.

Comment: @john `Doesn't seem to work` is not very helpful. What is wrong?

Comment: I need to store that big value of Binary

Comment: haha! clearly taken from ongoing contest @ www.codechef.com/NOV13/problems/SPOTWO

Answer (score 0):

you got a string and move to binary and then converts that string to an integer and then vc is the power, so that the whole supports a certain number of houses, so it's a blast, u can use paserInt putting the number of homes or turns the whole into a double.